# Property does not return value from private field

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, monodevelop, nullable

I'm facing a strange behaviour of one of my properties in my MonoTouch-Application.
It seems that the given value can not be returned by the Property, but the Debugger in MonoDevelop says that the private field in the background actually holds the value??

This is how the property got implemented:

```
public int? Status
{
    get { return this._status; }
    internal set
    {
        if (this._status != value)
        {
            // Status hat sich geändert, darum Speichervorgang nötig
            this._mustBeSaved = true;
            this._status = value;
            this.NotifyPropertyChanged("Status");
        }
    }
}
```

And here you can see what the Debugger says:

[image: Debugger]

How is it possible that the reflected value ("value") holds the correct value, and the reflected field "has_value" says that it's not holding any value at once? For this reason it's not possible to get the value from the property.

(The only difference between this and my other properties is that this property is nullable)

Answer (score 2):

`_value` is actually **null**. What you see in the debugger are internal fields and shouldn't be relied upon.

The compiler probably reuses the storage when you set the field to null, so that's why you're still seeing an old value in the internal `value` field. What counts are the public properties `HasValue` and `Value`.

Comment: True, though the debugger should really make this transparent, since the compiler does. I filed a bug: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=6282